# Rename Entries to Content on CP top menu

Tags: control-panel

A purely cosmetic change, but just wanted to know if its possible to change the menu item for Entries to something like Content? From a client point of view, I just know some will beg me to change this :)

Would also be handy to remove the Dashboard altogether as well for some cases.

Answer (score 3):

For custom "cosmetic" changes on the Control Panel there's these two Plugins by Lindsey DiLoreto:

- [Control Panel JS](https://github.com/lindseydiloreto/craft-cpjs)
- [Control Panel CSS](https://github.com/lindseydiloreto/craft-cpcss)

.

You can do both, hiding and renaming of menu items with CSS:

```css
#nav-dashboard {
  display: none;
}

#nav-entries a,
#nav-entries a:hover,
#nav-entries a:active {
  color: transparent;
  word-spacing: -9999px;
  letter-spacing: -9999px;
}

#nav-entries a:after {
  content: "Content";
  color: #d7d9db;
  word-spacing: normal;
  letter-spacing: normal; 
}

#nav-entries a:hover:after,
#nav-entries a:active:after {
  color: #fff;
}
```

Comment: Yeah aware of those two excellent plugins - however hiding/renaming stuff has a noticeable delay as jQuery seems to load. Sure, hiding through CSS is easy - but renaming is a little trickier!

Comment: @crawf yes, it's tricky and feels even more dirty then using JS for it, but it works.

Answer (score 3):

Explain to your clients politely that the whole CMS controls 'Content' and that the entries tab controls a specific type of content called 'Entries'!

Comment: Or you could create a craft localization called 'clients' (cl) with a translation file to translate everything into terms they can understand. ;)

Comment: The localization approach might be interesting! Any way I can make things easier for clients who think their browser is 'Google' is appreciated :)

Comment: Careful. I think 'cl' is actually Chile. hmmm... maybe 'us-en-cs' (US-English-Client-Speak)

Comment: Should be a standard language! heh ;)

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old but I've managed to remove the dashboard (from the navigation at least) with the following in a plugin's primary class. I guess there is nothing stopping you having a plugin that only does this!?

```
public function modifyCpNav(&$nav) {
    $newNav = array();
    foreach ($nav as $navKey => $navItem) {
        if ($navItem['label'] !== 'Dashboard') {
            $newNav[$navKey] = $navItem;
        }
    }
    $nav = $newNav;
}
```

You will need to set the postCpLoginRedirect config value to something otherwise it will still go to the dashboard page after login.

Comment: Yep - eventually created https://github.com/engram-design/CPNav that does just this!